# What is the Apple / OS X name for "Alternate Data Streams"?

Tags: filesystem, hfs+, terminology

On old Macs before OS X files already could have two "forks" - a data fork and a resource fork.

[According to Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HFS_Plus), at some point the HFS+ filesystem of OS X gained the ability to have an arbitrary number of forks, much like Microsofts "Alternate Data Streams" (`ADS`).

> HFS Plus permits filenames up to 255 UTF-16 characters in length, and n-forked files similar to NTFS, though until recently, almost no systems software takes advantage of forks other than the data fork and resource fork.

I want to know what the official term is for these forks or streams. I guess it's possible they're just called "forks" but that term has several meanings already in computing. I've done some searching but can't find a definitive answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just become interested in this topic again and started poking around.

This time I've noticed that the term **"named fork"** is widely used for forks other than the data fork and resource fork.

Here are some references:

- Archive of old Apple developer docs ["Using Pathnames"](https://web.archive.org/web/20030503064440/http://developer.apple.com:80/techpubs/macosx/Essentials/Performance/FilesNetworksThreads/Using_Pathnames.html)
- Mirror of old Apple developer docs ["Reading, Writing, and Closing Files"](http://mirror.informatimago.com/next/developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Reference/File_Manager/file_manager/function_group_41.html)
- Depreceated Apple developer docs ["Creating and Deleting Named Forks"](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coreservices/carbon_core/file_manager?language=objc)

Answer (score 5):

Apple uses "multiple fork" or the shortened form "multi-fork" consistently through its documentation, so it seems it is the official term. I list here a few examples:

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/SLGlobalGlossary/Glossary/Glossary.html (Last updated: 2010-07-09)

> HFS+  Hierarchical File System Plus. The Mac OS Extended file-system
>   format. This format adds support for filenames longer than 31
>   characters, Unicode representation of file and directory names, and
>   efficient operation on very large disks. **HFS+ is a multiple-fork
>   volume format.**

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Porting/Conceptual/PortingUnix/io_porting/io_porting.html (Last updated: 2012-06-11)

> (...) some Mac applications also take advantage of the HFS+ file
>   system’s ability to handle **multi-forked files**.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/AboutBundles/AboutBundles.html (Last updated: 2010-07-08)

> Bundles can reside on volumes of many different formats, including
>   **multiple fork** formats like HFS, HFS+, and AFP, and single-fork formats
>   like UFS, SMB, and NFS.

When talking about "fork" in computing I can only think of either HFS+/HFS forks or the system call for creating a child process.

Comment: What a great answer - thanks for your effort! (-:

Comment: Yes there is forking child processes and also forking projects, especially open source projects, as happened to OpenOffice->LibreOffice and WikiTravel->WikiVoyage. There may be other uses I don't know of too...

Comment: Oh God, I forgot fork in software development, thanks for pointing that out.